# Weird result when trying to draw a semi-transparent square over 1 of the 6 buttons in an ArrayList

Tags: java, opengl, arraylist, 2d

So I Have an ArrayList of buttons that I created, for the most part they work fine except this one thing. I'll go through the steps to reach the part that is giving me problems.

**The ArrayList Creation and Update**

```
private ArrayList<PressButton> buttons;

public CharacterSelectionMenu()
{
    buttons = new ArrayList<PressButton>();        
    addButtons();
}

public void update()
{
    updateButtons();
}

private void updateButtons()
{
    for(PressButton b : buttons)
    {
        b.update();
    }
}

private void addButtons()
{
    buttons.add(new CreateCharacterButton(100, 100, 64, 64));
    buttons.add(new CreateCharacterButton(200, 100, 64, 64));
    buttons.add(new CreateCharacterButton(300, 100, 64, 64));
    buttons.add(new CreateCharacterButton(100, 200, 64, 64));
    buttons.add(new CreateCharacterButton(200, 200, 64, 64));
    buttons.add(new CreateCharacterButton(300, 200, 64, 64));
}
```

**The method in the PressButton superclass that draws the square when hovering over the button**

```
public void update()
{
    input();
    draw();
    hover();
}

protected void hover()
{
    if(Collision.mouseAABBButton(this))
    {
        drawQuadColor(1, 1, 1, 0.3f, x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

**The drawQuadColor method (Just in case, this works everywhere I use it, I don't think it is the cause of the problem)**

```
public static void drawQuadColor(float r, float g, float b, float a, float x, float y,
        float width, float height)
{
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glColor4f(r, g, b, a);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(x, y);
    glVertex2f(x + width, y);
    glVertex2f(x + width, y + height);
    glVertex2f(x, y + height);
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
}
```

So here is the weird problem, I'm guessing it's very simple and has to do with the order of the updating in the ArrayList, but I'm too stupid to figure it out.

If I hover over the last button in the ArrayList it works just fine, like this:

[image]

But if I hover over any other button, the one that is being hovered over works like it should but the ones that are next in the ArrayList get a non-transparent square over them (shouldn't the "bugged" squares be transparent at least?), like this:

[image]

I have also tried using an Array instead but that did not help.

**How do I fix this and why does it happen?**

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing your `drawQuadColor` by

```
{
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glColor4f(r, g, b, a);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(x, y); 
    glVertex2f(x + width, y); 
    glVertex2f(x + width, y + height); 
    glVertex2f(x, y + height);
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
}
```

and update your question please ?

Comment: Nope, nothing changed.